# Blackhole Effects on World

Tags: planets, black-holes

An Earth-like planet orbits a Sun-like star. That whole system closely orbits a black hole, closely enough that the time shift is 100 to 1 (meaning 100 minutes pass on Earth while only 1 minute passes on this other planet).

What other differences would proximity to the black hole create? And are there reasonable explanations or phenomenon that could counteract those effects?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! [This similar question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/physiological-effects-of-living-on-a-world-close-to-a-black-hole) might give you an idea of the effects of living close to a black hole, but the second part of the question is a bit broad/opinion-based: either describe your world's magic system in more detail, or just focus on whether something in the real-world could counter the effects of living near a black hole.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Avilyn. Please note that the [tag:magic] tag specifically states that you need to define your magic system. Without that, it's impossible to determine if any answer is a solution to your problem and the entire topic becomes _primarily opinion-based_ or _too broad_, both reasons to place a question on hold.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your scenario also raises an interesting question about whether a sun *could* have a stable planet while close enough to a black hole that time dilation changes the relative velocities of the two bodies throughout their orbits. But maybe that one's more a question for physics.se. It intuitively feels like it should either totally cancel out and work, or explode rapidly: I'm not sure which.

Comment: Agreeing for now with the vote to close, though as already said, it can easily be fixed by removing the last four words and the tag, or defining the magic system to prevent answers like: a wizard could counteract the effects by waving his arms and saying "let the effects be counteracted!"

Comment: (a) Go watch the movie *Interstellar,* which tried to stay as close to our understanding of planets-near-black-holes as it could.  (b) This might get you a better answer if asked at [astronomy.se].

Comment: Mixing extreme science with magic is simply not a good plan, IMO.  You would need to explain your magical system in scientific terms (or good pseudo science) in order to develop a proper explanation for how the two interact.

Comment: Without the star ur only source of heat is the planet ability to generate heat and trap them like greenhouse, and to experience that kind of acceleration (gravity) I doubt a mere Sun-like star would suffice... I'm not fond of vtc but magic and science don't mix at least in this context.